# .net 3.5 logging to file from web.config

Tags: c#, .net, iis, logging, web-config

I have a .net 3.5 web site that works fine when I run it in Visual Studio.  However when we run it in IIS there are some errors.  What I would like to do is add some type of logging to the web.config so it logs what is happening to the website into a file.  Any good way of doing this?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code outputs log info using the built-in .NET System.Diagnostics.Trace functions, you can control and configure where those traces go using your web.config file.

In your code, use calls like

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("Your log info here");
```

In your web.config, set up an event log trace listener like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" 
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
          initializeData="TextWriterOutput.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

This will route the trace output from your program to the text file TextWriterOutput.log

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx

Comment: What's the path where the log file will be written?

Comment: Probably either the application bin directory, or user appdata. You can probably specify a complete filename path in the initializeData string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "happening to a file", but my preferred way to add logging is to use [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

NLog is available through [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), is powerful and quite easy to setup.  You can have different log actions for different types of errors.  For example, I log most things to a file, but also have Fatal errors send an email to the ops team, for many of my web apps that use NLog.

If that's not what you're looking for, please update your question to be more clear about the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most powerful (in my opinion) logging frameworks is [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). It can automatically log errors and you can also implement your own triggers for storing information in the logs.

Best of all, you can implement it without changes to the codebase. Only changes to web.config or machine.config are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a good logging framework like NLog (as suggested elsewhere). But if you just need something quick and dirty, consider adding some simple error handling to the Global.asax Application_Error event, like so (free from memory):

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get error and log objects
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\path\\to\\log.txt");

    // Write out what you need and close the file
    log.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    log.Close();

    // Redirect to error page ..
}
```

Remember to make sure you have the necessary permissions to open/create the log file as well.